# jest enzyme mount - Cannot ready property of undefined when checking this.props.location.query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component with the following componentDidMount() method:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let seconds = 0;

    if(this.props.location.query.seconds) {
     seconds = parseInt(this.props.location.query.seconds, 10);
    }

    if (seconds > 0) {
      this.setState({count:seconds});
      window.location.hash = '#/timer';
    }
  }
```

I am also setting the state in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: 180,
      countdownStatus: 'stopped'
    };

    this.handleStatusChange = this.handleStatusChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSetCountdown = this.handleSetCountdown.bind(this);
    this.handleSliderInput = this.handleSliderInput.bind(this);
  }
```

Then I am passing the state to another component with the render

```
function:
  render() {
    let {count, countdownStatus} = this.state;
    return(
      <div className="content-card timer-card">
        <h1 className="title">Tea timer</h1>
        <Clock totalSeconds={count} status={countdownStatus}/>
        {renderStartStop()}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Now I want to write a test that checks that the props are getting passed correctly:

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';

import Timer from './Timer.component';

describe('<Timer/>', () => {
  it('pass count to Clock as totalSeconds', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Timer />);
    wrapper.instance().props.location.query.seconds = 180;
    expect(wrapper.find('Clock').prop('totalSeconds').toEqual(180));
  })
});
```

But I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
>
> ```
>   at Timer.componentDidMount (src/Timer/Timer.component.js:26:28)
>   at node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:265:25
>   at measureLifeCyclePerf (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:75:12)
>   at node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:264:11
>   at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (node_modules/react-dom/lib/CallbackQueue.js:76:22)
>   at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactReconcileTransaction.js:80:26)
>   at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (node_modules/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js:206:25)
>   at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (node_modules/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js:153:16)
>   at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js:126:15)
>   at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (node_modules/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js:140:20)
>   at Object.batchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62:26)
>   at Object.batchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactUpdates.js:97:27)
>   at Object._renderNewRootComponent (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js:320:18)
>   at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js:401:32)
>   at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js:422:23)
>   at Object.renderIntoDocument (node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactTestUtils.js:79:21)
>   at renderWithOptions (node_modules/enzyme/build/react-compat.js:187:26)
>   at new ReactWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:94:59)
>   at mount (node_modules/enzyme/build/mount.js:19:10)
>   at Object.it (src/Timer/Timer.test.js:13:65)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
> ```

Shouldn't this be mitigated by the `if(this.props.location.query.seconds)` check?

I only posted the relevant parts, since this component is a bit big, but if you need more info the whole component is [here](https://github.com/Shooshte/teaTimer/blob/rewrite/src/Timer/Timer.component.js). Please also comment if some critical information is needed so I can update the question.

Answer (score 1):

So, a couple of things to note here:

The first one is that the initial check was wrong - I first needed to check if this.props were an object, and if it has the seconds key nested anywhere. So I modified the componentDidMount method:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // function for checking if an argument is a object
    let isObj = (variable) => (variable !== null) && (typeof variable === 'object');
    // function for checking if an object has a specific nested key
    let objHasKey = (obj, key) => {
      return isObj(obj) ? (key in obj) || Object.values(obj).filter(nestedObj => objHasKey(nestedObj, key)).length > 0 : false;
    };

    let seconds = 0;
    if(objHasKey(this.props, 'seconds')) {
     seconds = parseInt(this.props.location.query.seconds, 10);
    }
    if (seconds > 0) {
      this.setState({count:seconds});
      window.location.hash = '#/timer';
    }
  }
```

Then I split the tests into two categories, one when passing props to the component, and one without:

```
  it('pass state countdownStatus to Clock as status', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Timer />);
    const status = wrapper.state('countdownStatus');
    expect(wrapper.find('Clock').prop('status')).toEqual(status);
  });
  it('set this.props.location.query.seconds as state.count when passed', () => {
    const mockUrl = {
      query : {
        seconds: '100'
      }
    }
    const wrapper = mount(<Timer location={mockUrl}/>);
    expect(wrapper.state('count')).toEqual(100);
  })
```